# ruby on rails create new record for a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code below create a new project in database record.It takes in parameters like job_location and project_title,contact_person.

```
 def new
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

Now I want to convert the job_location to latitude and longitude use other web-service(input address,out put a pair of numbers) and store into database. The convert part is done.

where should I add code to transfer this address to number and store in database?

I have tried add

```
@project.update_attributes(lat: 10 ,lng: 11)
```

At end of new function,but doesn't work.

I don't know how to retrieve data (just inputted by user)

don't know how to put converted data into database.

where and what code should add to achieve this?

Comment: try appending that conversion code in create action like `params[:project][:job_location] = #your conversion code here`

Comment: I find add @project.update_attributes(lat: 10 ,lng: 11) under create instead of new will update the database~

Comment: does it worked? do you have the lat and lng attributes in your projects table

Comment: Your `projects` table should have `lat` and `lng` fields for it to work. Further more, you have to pass a hash in `update_attributes` method. like this `@project.update_attributes({lat: 10 ,lng: 11})`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) to add *lat* and *lng* to your database.

If you can't change your database, maybe you just convert *lat* and *lng* to your struct and then save it into database.

Comment: database part no problem,can change anytime.How to use struct in detail?I'm a newbie of ror

Comment: Nothing magical here, I mean that you should convert _lat_ and _lng_ to a data structure and then save it to an exist column in your db.

How can you add data to a column that not exist!

Did you know how to use Migration to add columns into db?